# Regex optional group (Music Tagging)

Tags: regex

Firstly, let me thank anyone willing to take the time to help me! This is probably a ridiculously easy question but i've been breaking my head over it...

I'm cleaning up my music library and i've got an enormous amount of incorrectly tagged songs. The filename does have the correct info though so I'm tagging from filename. Currently this works fine with ID3Tag (tag from file) in the following context.

```
(.*) - (.*) - (.*)
```

TIEKS - Sunshine - Radio Edit

But I also have songs that don't have a third part:

```
(.*) - (.*) ?: -(.*)
```

Jason Derulo - Kiss the Sky

And now the expression does not work anymore. I tried making the last part optional by using the ?: parameter but this does not seem to work.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Try: `(.*) - (.*)(?: - (.*))?`

Comment: Or instead of matching any character with `.*` specify what you want to match in a character class and make the last group including the hyphen optional  [`([\w ]+\w) - ([\w ]+\w)(?: - ([\w ]+\w))?`](https://regex101.com/r/wdei7F/1)

Comment: Use [`^((?:(?! - ).)*) - ((?:(?! - ).)*)(?: - (.*))?$`](https://regex101.com/r/fUdFHK/2)

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^(.*?) - (.*?)(?: - (.*))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fUdFHK/3)

The point is to match the first two `.`s lazy with `*?` quantifiers and use an optional non-capturing group at the end to wrap the optional third part.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `-`  - a space, `-`, a space
- `(.*?)` -  - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?: - (.*))?` - an optional non-capturing group (`(?:...)?`) that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `<code> - </code> - a space,`-`, a space
  - `(.*)` -  - Group 3: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.